# Trying to Select All XMLNodes in Word Document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I'm playing with making a plugin for Microsoft Word (C#), and I want to get all the XMLNodes that the document is stored in (as it's a DOCX file).

Word's API has a SelectNodes function that takes an xpath, but I'm getting null when I try different parameters. I'm trying to select *all* nodes (for now), and thus I don't think it is a namespace issue (but I could be wrong). Here's the relevant code:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
Word.XMLNodes docNodes = Doc.SelectNodes("//*");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We have node count: " + docNodes.Count.ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < docNodes.Count; i++)
{
   Word.XMLNode node = docNodes[i];
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(node.get_XML());
}
```

It's failing when I try to use docNodes, because the call to Doc.SelectNodes returned null. I'm running this over a Word document -- literally created by clicking "new document" in Word and then typing in some text into a few paragraphs.

I can't find good documentation or examples on here or on MSDN for how to get this function to yield results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can certainly be confusing, but...

When you work with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, you are really using Automation to access Word's object model. But the object model does not really know anything about the XML inside a .docx file (with some exceptions as described below). If you want to inspect the XML that's actually inside a .docx on disk, you really need to use either the Ofice Open XML SDK, or perhaps the Packaging interfaces.

So why is there a "SelectNodes" member of the Document object? Well, it's there to let you select "Custom XML" nodes. But these are no longer supported in Word - as a consequence of a lawsuit a few years ago, Microsoft removed support from the U.S. version of Word 2007, then at some point from all later versions of Word. You can in fact still insert such nodes (in, say Word 2010) via a thing called the XML Structure pane. But if you save the document and re-open, this type of Custom XML will be gone.

Despite the name, this type of thing is not the same thing as the XML in Custom XML Parts. Custom XML Parts are developer-designed data areas for storing "whatever XML you want" inside a .docx. FOr example, SharePoint uses Custom XML Parts as a mechanism for storing properties defined in "SharePoint columns" - Word can display this property data in "Content Controls". It is possible to retrieve and manipulate XML Nodes in Custom XML Parts.

FInally, if you need to inspect or manipulate the XML that Word is actually using to represent your document *via the Object model* you can do that in a limited way using the XML or WordOpenXML properties of the Range, Selection or Document object. (The XML is a representation in Word 2003 XML format. The WordOpenXML is a representation in Word OOXML Flat OPC format). But bear in mind that you only really get to see the XML that Word needs to represent the specific piece of the document that you extract - you never get to see the complete XML of the document this way, and you can't really assume that the XML that Word will save on disk wil be the same.